# Dark color appearing on the frame while executing the cefpython code in ubuntu VM 16.04

Tags: wxpython, cefpython

I have referred [this link](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython). where you can see the branches from their goto examples/wxpython.py copy that file and execute the code in window platform it's working fine on **window** platform but in **Ubuntu virtual machine 16.04 version** the frame turning to dark color.

Please help me on this issue.

[image]

Comment: Install all Ubuntu updates and see if that makes a difference. Update wxPython to latest version as well.

Comment: Still, issue retaining. I am currently using **CEF Python 57.0**, **Python 2.7.12 64bit**, **wxPython 4.0.0a3.dev3059+4a5c5d9 gtk3 (phoenix)** and **Virtual machine 16.04**. Is it anything need to update and check the above image while executing code it appears like that.

Comment: @Czarek Tomczak I have installed cefpython of **sudo pip install cefpython3==57.0**. Is it right for the ubuntu VM server?

Comment: You're using ALPHA/DEV version of wxPython, go download a STABLE version. Yes, command to install cefpython is OK.

Comment: @Czarek Tomczak As I am less aware of technology I don't know much ideas of the stable version. can you please send me the link to install the stable version of wxpython

Comment: @Czarek Tomczak I have installed latest version **wxpython** to **4.0.1 gtk3 (phoenix)** from https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04/ . Still same issue retaining.

Comment: Try wxPython with gtk2.

Comment: Run the original unmodified wxpython.py example

Comment: Also try running wxPython demos to see if it's wxpython issue or cefpython issue

Comment: @Czarek Tomczak  Now I updated to 4.0.0a1 gtk2 (phoenix) it's working fine but getting some errors `[0329/150104.391366:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(583)] Failed to call method: org.gnome.SessionManager.Inhibit: object_path= /org/gnome/SessionManager: org.gnome.SessionManager.GeneralError: Application ID not specified
[0329/150104.391487:ERROR:power_save_blocker_x11.cc(335)] No response to Inhibit() request!`

Comment: `[wxpython.py] OnClose called
[0329/150213.926711:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(583)] Failed to call method: org.gnome.SessionManager.Uninhibit: object_path= /org/gnome/SessionManager: org.gnome.SessionManager.GeneralError: Unable to uninhibit: Invalid cookie
[0329/150213.926811:ERROR:power_save_blocker_x11.cc(407)] No response to Uninhibit() request!`

Comment: "a1" in version number means ALPHA - UNSTABLE.

Comment: Looks like the issues you're having are wxpython related. Best to ask on wxpython support forum.

Comment: ok will post. is it possible to create custom panel where I can bind the cefpython?